# CSS working in CodePen but not working when I copy it to my editor

Tags: html, css, codepen

This is a small code snippet I got from CodePen. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when I copy and try to use it. Is there something I'm missing? How can I make this code work in my editor and browser?

```
ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;

     li {
        list-style: none;
     }
}
```

Also, is this the same as,

```
ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
 }
```

P.S. : This is only a very simple example. The real code has lots of such "nested" selectors.(Going up to 5 "nested" selectors)

Comment: To answer your question, we need a little more information. Could you show your HTML code?

Comment: I just want to know the solution to something this simple. If I know how to fix it for something so small, then I'd be able to fix the error myself. 
Besides, the HTML code is around 200 lines of code. 
Just need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First code snippet that's in your question (with those nested selectors) is not a CSS.

It might work like CSS in the second snippet, but to do so, you need to use Preprocessor such as SASS/LESS/SCSS/etc, which are using simplified syntax to render CSS as it should be.

If you look around, you'll find out what preprocessor is used in the CodePen you mentioned.

[image: currently used preprocessor]

[image: where to change preprocessor]

Answer (score 0):

1. Most probabbly because in first example is SASS type of CSS, which automatically compiling in CodePen, however it's not, **in your's IDE,**
2. Second example is pure CSS, so if you want that those snippet start working, you need to take out all that nested properties, or just compile that SASS to CSS
3. Or attach that full snippet that you want to copy